# About $\delta$-neighborhood and a region of a single point

Tags: general-topology, definition

Can a single point be called a region? I'm reading $\delta$-neighborhood in my calculus book, *Calculus, Larson, 10th ed.* p.880, and it's not clear for me what's the precise definition of region:

[image]

If a single point could be a region, then that point would not be a interior point. And it's not clear whether *points inside $R$* including that point. If it is not included then it is not a boundary... So wt_ is that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a subset of $ \mathbb R^2$, then $R$ is called open if every point of $R$ is an interior point of $R$.

$R$ is called a region if $R$ is open  and connected and $R \ne \emptyset$.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_(mathematics)

So I can not agree with the definition in your book

Comment: But there is no definition of a region in this piece. Just open region.

Comment: My conclusion is a point can't be a region, is this correct?